# How to properly share Hapi Joi validation schemas between models without circular dependency

Tags: javascript, architecture, hapi.js, joi

I am creating an API using HAPI and Joi to validate inputs and I am having troubles with sharing my validation schema between different modules.
I am using a component-oriented architecture that looks like that

```
components
|_ moduleA
   |_ moduleAController
   |_ moduleAModel
   |_ moduleARoute
   |_ moduleAValidate
|_ moduleB
   |_ moduleBController
   |_ moduleBModel
   |_ moduleBRoute
   |_ moduleBValidate
|_ moduleC
...
```

In each module, `moduleXRoute` create a route associating a handler from `moduleXController` and a validator from `moduleXValidate`.

As I am using Joi, I am performing some tests on input data and that where comes the problem, my `moduleA` keeps a list of `moduleB` and my `moduleB` keeps a reference to `moduleA`, thus this implies in the validators :

```
var moduleASchema = {
    _id: Joi.objectId(),
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    moduleB: Joi.array().items(Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.objectId(), moduleBSchema)),
};

var moduleBSchema = {
        _id: Joi.objectId(),
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        moduleA: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.objectId(), moduleASchema),
};
```

That's why, I think it would be a good idea that `moduleAValidate` and `moduleBValidate` expose `moduleASchema` and `moduleBSchema` that other modules could use.

The problem is that it makes a circular dependency problem because in the case above, I would have:

```
//moduleAValidate.js
var moduleBSchema = require('../moduleBValidate').moduleBschema;

//moduleBValidate.js
var moduleASchema = require('../moduleAValidate').moduleAschema;
```

Thus, what would be the good way to handle the problem ?

I found the easy way would be to centralize all schemas in a single file that could be required in all validators, but I feel it like it would just be in contradiction with component-architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to have a central point where common parts of schemas are kept in a central place and loaded into the required schemas when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to solve the chicken-and-egg problem by using dependency injection.
In the above example, I would do something like

```
//moduleBValidate.js
var moduleBSchema = new (require('moduleBSchema.js'))();
var moduleASchema = new (require('moduleASchema.js'))(moduleBSchema); // Here I use dependency injection for injecting moduleBSchema in moduleASchema

//moduleAValidate.js
var moduleASchema = new (require('moduleASchema.js'))();
var moduleBSchema = new (require('moduleBSchema.js'))(moduleASchema);
```

And I built the joi schema this way:

```
function moduleASchema(moduleBSchema, moduleCSchema...) { // Here we put all dependencies of moduleASChema
    moduleBSchema = moduleBSchema || Joi.object();
    moduleCSchema = moduleCSchema || Joi.object();
    ...

    this.schema = {
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        moduleBRef: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.objectId(), moduleBSchema),
        moduleCRef: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.objectId(), moduleCSchema)
    };
    return this.schema;
}

module.exports = SiteSchema;
```